# how to fix json_encode return empty array or empty object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, foreach

I need help of some advanced users of PHP, JSON, AJAX and jQuery. I need to use json_encode in foreach loop between two if statemnts, so I'm reading a lot on google and I was find somewhere that ***$jsonData=[];*** need be declared before first if statement, but in this case when a form is submitted var_dump of jsonData return empty array or empty object if I add `echo json_encode($jsonData, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` Also, without JS file form is submitted correctly and all data is inserted into the database as well. However, this is my JSON returned when I comment JS file when a form is submitted: `{"0":{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam Testing! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}}` or if I use just `echo json_encode($jsonData)` I get seguent JSON `[{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam John Doe! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}]` However on `https://jsonlint.com/` all twoo JSON it's valid JSON, but I can not figure out how to process it in jQuery for get this data on web page.
Hier it's PHP file with part of json_encode

```
$query_m = "SELECT owners_email.email_address_id, email_address, owner_name, owner_property, owner_sex, owner_type FROM visitneum.owners_email INNER JOIN visitneum.pages ON (pages.email_address_id = owners_email.email_address_id) WHERE `owner_sex`='M' AND `owner_type`='other' AND `pages_id` = ?";
    $dbstmt = $pdo->prepare($query_m);
    $dbstmt->bindParam(1,$pages_id);
    $dbstmt->execute();
    $emails_other = $dbstmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $jsonData=[];
    if(is_array($emails_other) && count($emails_other) > 0){
        foreach ($emails_other as $email_other){
        //var_dump($email_other['email_address']);
            $mailOwner->addAddress($email_other['email_address']);
                $body_other = "<p>Poštovani {$email_other['owner_name']}, <br>" . "Upravo ste primili poruku sa sajta <a href='https://www.visit-neum.com'>visit-neum.com</a><br>Detalji Vaše poruke se nalaze ispod:</p><p><strong>Od: </strong>" . ucwords($fname) . "<br><strong>Telefon: </strong>" . $tel . "<br><strong>E-mail: </strong>" .strtolower($userMail)."<br><strong>Poruka: </strong>" . $userMessage . "<br><br><strong>Napomena: </strong>Molimo Vas da na ovu poruku ne odgovarate. Vaš odgovor pošaljite na: " . strtoupper($userMail) . "</p>";
                $mailOwner->Body = $body_other;         
                try {
                    $mailOwner->send();
                    $mailOwner = "INSERT INTO visitneum.contact_owner (fname, tel, userMail, userMessage, email_address_id) VALUES (:fname, :tel, :userMail, :userMessage, :email_address_id)";
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($mailOwner);
                    $stmt->execute(['fname' => $fname, 'tel' => $tel, 'userMail' => $userMail, 'userMessage' => $userMessage, 'email_address_id' => $email_other['email_address_id']]);

                    $rez['response']="success";
                    $rez['content']="Hvala Vam ".ucwords($fname)."! Vaša poruka je uspješno poslata vlasniku objekta {$email_other['owner_property']}! Odgovor ćete dobiti ubrzo!";
                    $jsonData[] = $rez;
                }//end try mail send    
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    $rez['response'] = "error";
                    $rez['content'] = "Došlo je do greške! Pokušajte ponovo..." . $mailOwner->ErrorInfo;
                    $jsonData[] = $rez;
                }       
    }//end foreach for email addresses  (man owners of other properties(restaurants, ships etc.))
}//end if for array of emails
//echo str_replace("[]", "{}", json_encode($jsonData));
echo json_encode($jsonData);
//var_dump($jsonData);
```

And this is part of my JS file after submitHandler

```
     submitHandler: function (form) {
      //Your code for AJAX starts    
      var formData = jQuery("#contactOwner").serialize();
      console.log(formData);
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/inc/Form_process.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        //async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (rez) {
          jQuery("#responseOwner").text(rez[0].content);
          console.log(rez[0].response);
          console.log(rez[0].content);
        }, error: function (rez) {
         jQuery("#responseOwner").text("An error occurred");
          console.log(rez[1].response);
          console.log(rez[1].content);
        }
      }); //Code for AJAX Ends
      // Clear all data after submit
      var resetForm = document.getElementById('contactOwner').reset();
      return false;
    } //submitHandler
```

I hope that somebody understand why json_encode return just empty array or empty object with `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`, so thanks in advance for any kind of your help. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: try adding **die()**  at last in php file

Comment: So what does your JSON look like? It seems strange not to include that in your question since that’s where the problem is

Comment: Dear @Synchro, thanks a lot for answer me. I was included JSON in PHP file, please check up. However, problem is with $data['response'] and $data['content']. Maybe JSON can not work inside foreach...

Comment: if you use dataType: 'json' in ajax, u dont need to call JSON.stringify

Comment: @Synchro this is response which get in console: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}, so because responseText is an empty string this mean that my JSON is not a valid JSON, but the some JSON is valid if I dont use foreach for get email addresses from mysql db, beacuse in so many other sites I used exactly the some JSON.

Comment: Dear @johnSmith isn't metter, I was allready try, with and without, however doesnt't work. I think sure that with multiple addresses need use different style of JSON, or maybe isn't possible to use JSON inside foreach loop.

Comment: _"because responseText is an empty string this mean that my JSON is not a valid"_ - An empty string is perfectly valid. But please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67444819/edit) your question to include the complete response instead of in a comment. For example, the `,` after the json in your comment, is that from the actual response, or did you just add it in the comment?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, complete response is without comma, so  this is response{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}

Comment: You should create one single array which you populate in your foreach and then _after_ the foreach, you encode/echo it as json. Then it will become an array with objects in json. Right now, you're just outputting multiple json objects after each other inside the loop, which will be invalid json

Comment: @MagnusEriksson how you can see responseText is just an empty string and on google you can find so many thousend tutorials which says that this mean that your JSON is not valid. However, when using textStatus for this error I get parseerror  and for ErrorThrown I get Syntax error: Unexpected end of JSON input. What mean AJAX Error: parseerror and what mean Syntax error: Unexpected end of JSON input?! I read whatever try to find on google about it, and again can not understand why my JSON is not valid, because everywhere write that this mean that your JSON isn't valid.

Comment: I don't know what sites you read that on or who wrote it, but `{"foo": ""}` is perfectly valid JSON so your `"responseText":""` is not causing it to be invalid. If anyone claims it will, then they are factually wrong, or you've misunderstood the context of that claim. However, you've already gotten an answer which explains your _actual_ issue in detail.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I was edited code and included JSON `{"0":{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam Testing! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}}
` or `[{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam John Doe! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}]` which is returned when a form is submitted, but in jQuery it return an empty array or empty object if I use JSON_FORCE_OBJECT. Please can you check it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have another issue, please post a new question with a full explanation and code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I was try, but can not, so stackowerflow suggested me to edit my code and I was completely change and update my question. Please can you read and tell me if `{"0":{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam Testing! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}}` or `[{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam John Doe! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}]` it's valid JSON, why when can not get this data with jQuery and AJAX on the web page?

Comment: That is not ok! _Never_ change a question after you've gotten answers. If you do, the comments or answers won't make sense for future visitors. Stack Overflow doesn't suggested you to change the question after the fact. If you think it has, you have misunderstood something. Why can't you ask another question? What happens? What does Stack Overflow _actually_ say? Please roll back the question to it's previous state.

Comment: I dont get never answer that helped me, so I think that nobody understand what is my problem. For this reason I was change my question for explain better what is my problem, with some update of my code which explain better where is the problem.

Comment: @Synchro please can you check now why can not get data of php  json_encode in jQuery  and AJAX. Without JS fil mail is sent successfully and I get valid JSON with success insert data into db. This is JSON which is returned when a form is submitted `[{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam John Doe! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}]` , but for me it's impossible to display this data on the web page with jQuery and AJAX. Please check and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You really should include the actual JSON in your question; without it we are working blind, but I can guess what the problem is. You are not constructing your JSON properly when there are multiple records. When you have a single recipient, your JSON might look like this:

```json
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

That is fine, and perfectly valid JSON – and there is no issue having an empty string as a value. The problem arises when you have more than one record, when it will append them immediately after the first:

```json
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

This is *not* valid JSON.

I suggest you accumulate your JSON responses inside the loop and then output them afterwards, in the correct format. Something like:

```php
$jsonData = [];
foreach ($emails_room_f as $email_room_f){
    //set your content in $data as you are now, then:
    $jsonData[] = $data;
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

This way you will end up with data like this:

```json
[
    {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"},
    {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
]
```

Which *is* valid JSON. It will also work if there is no data as it will return an empty array, which is also valid JSON.

Separately from this, I am extremely suspicious of you having a `utf8ize` function – that is a sign you're doing other UTF-8 stuff wrong, but that's a subject for another question.

Comment: That is PHP code that creates an array that is later converted to JSON; it is *not* JSON itself, nor does it show the actual content that is triggering your error.

Comment: If you only want a single response, don't accumulate things inside the loop, just keep track of the overall status and output the JSON *after* the loop.

Comment: Did you read my answer at all? You have still not posted the JSON you are producing despite being asked several times. You're really not helping us help you here. It's likely that responseText is empty because you're returning invalid JSON, so it's failing to parse the data that it would normally use to populate that. This is why we keep asking you to post your JSON! It would be a good idea to test your PHP independently of your JS as you are getting confused between the two.

Comment: OK, but don't just change things randomly and hope it works, understand what it is you're doing and why.

Comment: please can you check now my correct php file and jQuery. I was included to JSON returned when a form is submitted, which is correct JSON on `https://jsonlint.com/` but however on submit it return empty array or empty object. Why? I can not figure out :(

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn how to use a debugger: set a breakpoint in your PHP, step through the code and watch what happens when it handles a request. At a guess, given that `$jsonData` starts out as an empty array, and you have a fair amount of error checking means that it may remain empty - so double check that your code is actually being run.

Comment: I was edited complete my PHP and jQuery code, so please can you check it, because I think that the problem is in jQuery file.When I comment submitHandler, email is sent successfully, data inserted into db and I get valid JSON `{"0":{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam Testing! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}}  or without JSON_FORCE_OBJECT [{"response":"success","content":"Hvala Vam John Doe! Va\u0161a poruka je uspje\u0161no poslata vlasniku objekta Brod Ivana! Odgovor \u0107ete dobiti ubrzo!"}]`